# c# how can I detect load dll from other process

Tags: c#, dll, loading, detect

Hi firstly sorry my bad english.

I want to create trainer,cheat for the game. Firstly loader is running and load the main game executable file. After than game protection software is running and downloading new dll file from the server and owerwrite to old one.(patch is doesnt work) Is everythink okey than target.dll is loading and run. 
I find which offset address is will be patch in dll file. But how can I detect when its loading to memory ?
I'm trying this code

```
IntPtr hid = GetModuleHandle("target.dll");
```

But its returned 0.

OS is W7 SP1

Thanx..

Answer (score 0):

`GetModuleHandle` returns a handle to the module in your process, not another process.

To monitor the loading of DLLs in another process you'll need to be running your application as a debugger which is "debugging" the application you want to monitor. You can do this using the [debugging API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809754.aspx) and handling the **LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT** event.

You many need to use C/C++ to do this...

Comment: Okey, if its possible get main exe PID and search signature of target .dll files all threads with main exe memory areas ?
If this process take only 1 or 2 seconds loading and running and killing  Can I catch in the memory and patch in 2 second?

Comment: If you want to patch process memory you'll need to use the `WriteProcessMemory` api (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx). However, this all requires you to be acting as a debugger to the process in the first place. How long it will take depends on what and how you're scanning for.